# SwiftUI 2 questions but very simple, about searchBar and the backgroundImage for List

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI very simple 2 questions

1, how to make the searchBar stick to top so that when use scroll down they can still see they searchBar

2, I'm using a List and work with a TabView and I want the List or the `VStack` maybe(or something that is holding the List) to have a background Image(a png already in my Assets.xcassets). I tried `ZStack` or `.background(Image("..."))` but none of them worked.

Here is the image, I want the background to be as the teal color png image.

[image]

Here is the code of one of the view for TabView:

```
 struct Discover: View {
    @State private var keywords: String = ""
    var names = ["Yu Song", "ZhangYuan", "Kotoyama"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                HStack {
                    SearchBar(text: $keywords)
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Image(systemName: "bell")
                }
                ForEach(self.names.filter {
                    self.keywords.isEmpty ? true : $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.keywords)
                }, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }.background(Image("bg_global"))
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

here is the preview for your convinence:
[image]

Notice that I already added `.background(Image("bg_global"))` in List and `VSrack` but the image never showed.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To make background visible it's needed to make `List` and its content transparent. It can be done for example in `init`,

```
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `VStack` instead of a `ZStack` to make the `SearchBar` stick to the top. And make sure the `SearchBar` is not part of the `List` View.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    @State private var keywords: String = ""
    var names = ["Yu Song", "ZhangYuan", "Kotoyama"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            // Your Search Bar View
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Text("Search")
                Spacer()
            }.padding().background(Color.red)

            List {
                ForEach(self.names.filter {
                    self.keywords.isEmpty ? true : $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(self.keywords)
                }, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
        }.offset(x: 0, y: 45).background(Color.yellow).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Since you also want to show the background in the safe areas you need to push down the view with `offset`.